# How to get html-table tbody inputs value that are dumped by lodash _.template?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, lodash

This is a Basic Html table to dump tbody by using lodash _.template.
Html Table is:

```
    <div id="attribute-values-wrapper">
        <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="options table table-bordered">
                       <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody id="attribute-values">
                       </tbody>
                 </table>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Lodash _.template is:

```
    <script type="text/html" id="attribute-value-template">
      <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <span class="drag-icon">
            <i class="fa">&#xf142;</i>
            <i class="fa">&#xf142;</i>
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>
     <input type="hidden" name="values[<%- valueId %>][id]"
         value="<%- value.id %>">
    
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="values[<%- valueId %>][value]"
    value="<%- value.value %>" class="form-control">
 </div>
          </td>
       <td class="text-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete-row"
      data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Delete Value">
              <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
     </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </script>
```

Simple javascript function to dump tbody.

```
let valuesCount = 0;
function addAttributeValue(value = {id: '', value: ''}) {
    let template = _.template($('#attribute-value-template').html());
    let html = template({valueId: valuesCount++, value});
    $('#attribute-values').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question.

```
let attribute_values = [];
    $('#attribute-values tr').each(function (index, element) {
        let inputs = $(this).find('input'), o = {};
        inputs.each(function () {
            let name = $(this).attr('name');
            if (name === "values[" + index + "][id]") {
                o["id"] = this.value;
            } else if (name === "values[" + index + "][value]") {
                o["value"] = this.value;
            }
        });
        attribute_values.push(o);
    });
```